# SSL Secure Renegotiation with .NET SslStream

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ssl

I'm trying to do secure renegotiation with .NET SslStream, but I'm not sure how to achieve it, or if it is even possible. My goal is to renew the shared secret, using the same certificate for the server.

I set up a server using OpenSSL :

```
s_server -accept 443 -key privkey.pem
```

Here's my client code :

```
public static void RunClient()
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 443);
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(innerStream: client.GetStream(), leaveInnerStreamOpen: true, userCertificateValidationCallback: (a,b,c,d) => true, userCertificateSelectionCallback: null);
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");
    byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from the client.");
    sslStream.Write(message);
    sslStream.Dispose();
    // if code below is commented, there's no error.
    sslStream = new SslStream(innerStream: client.GetStream(), leaveInnerStreamOpen: true, userCertificateValidationCallback: (a, b, c, d) => true, userCertificateSelectionCallback: null);
    message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from the client again, renegotiated.");
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");
    sslStream.Write(message);
    //
    client.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Client closed.");
}

public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    RunClient();
    return 0;
}
```

The second call to AuthenticateAsClient, on the new SslStream fails with "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.". The inner exception is "Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted".

On the server side, I get an error too :

```
CIPHER is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Hello from the client.ERROR
8404:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:469:
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
ACCEPT
```

Do you know what's wrong here, or if my use case is even supported with SslStream ?

Comment: I know nothing about C#/.NET but reading your code it does not seem to be to session resumption, you are just opening a new TLS handshake on the previous TCP connections, which is ok to fail I think. Renegotiation/Resumption would surely need to use some specific parameters/methods to be used in the TLS stream (and this also depends on the TLS version used).

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120380_.html says: *Although the SSLStream class does not support secret key resetting or renegotiation, ...*

Comment: Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.5.2 I think it is because you are setting "leaveInnerStreamOpen" to true.  A Remark on that page states: When you specify true for the leaveStreamOpen parameter, closing the SslStream has no effect on the innerStream stream; you must explicitly close innerStream when you no longer need it.  If you set that to false does it work?